# How to get count dict of items but maintain the order in which they appear?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, ordereddictionary

For example, I need to count how many times a word appears in a list, not sorted by frequency but with the order in which the words appear, i.e. insertion order.

```
from collections import Counter

words = ['oranges', 'apples', 'apples', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'kiwis', 'apples']

c = Counter(words)

print(c)
```

So instead of: `{'apples': 3, 'kiwis': 2, 'bananas': 1, 'oranges': 1}`

I'd rather get: `{'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2}`

And I don't really need this `Counter` method, any way that will produce correct result is OK for me.

Comment: Related: [Creating an Ordered Counter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446015/creating-an-ordered-counter/52173924)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) that uses `collections.Counter` and `collections.OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)

words = ["oranges", "apples", "apples", "bananas", "kiwis", "kiwis", "apples"]
c = OrderedCounter(words)
print(c)
# OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('oranges', 1), ('apples', 3), ('bananas', 1), ('kiwis', 2)]))
```

Answer (score 13):

On Python 3.6+, `dict` will now maintain insertion order.

So you can do:

```
words = ["oranges", "apples", "apples", "bananas", "kiwis", "kiwis", "apples"]
counter={}
for w in words: counter[w]=counter.get(w, 0)+1
>>> counter
{'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2}
```

Unfortunately, the Counter in Python 3.6 and 3.7 does not display the insertion order that it maintains; instead, `__repr__` [sorts the return](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L703) by the most to least common.

But you can use the same OrderedDict [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes) but just use the Python 3.6+ dict instead:

```
from collections import Counter

class OrderedCounter(Counter, dict):
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, dict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (dict(self),)

>>> OrderedCounter(words)
OrderedCounter({'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2})
```

Or, since Counter is a subclass of `dict` that maintains order in Python 3.6+, you can just avoid using Counter's `__repr__` by either calling `.items()` on the counter or turning the counter back into a `dict`:

```
>>> c=Counter(words)
```

This presentation of that Counter is sorted by most common element to least and uses Counters `__repr__` method:

```
>>> c
Counter({'apples': 3, 'kiwis': 2, 'oranges': 1, 'bananas': 1})
```

This presentation is as encountered, or insertion order:

```
>>> c.items()
dict_items([('oranges', 1), ('apples', 3), ('bananas', 1), ('kiwis', 2)])
```

Or,

```
>>> dict(c)
{'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2}
```

Answer (score 1):

In **Python 3.6**, dictionaries are insertion ordered, but this is an implementation detail.

In **Python 3.7+**, insertion order is guaranteed and can be relied upon. See [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39980744/9209546) for more details.

So, depending on your Python version, you may wish to just use `Counter` as is, without creating an `OrderedCounter` class as described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes). This works because `Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, i.e. `issubclass(Counter, dict)` returns `True`, and therefore inherits the insertion ordering behaviour of `dict`.

**String representation**

It is worth noting the the string representation for `Counter`, as defined in the `repr` method, [has not been updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52174284/how-are-counter-defaultdict-ordered-in-python-3-7) to reflect the change in 3.6 / 3.7, i.e. `print(Counter(some_iterable))` still returns items from largest counts descending. You can trivially return the insertion order via `list(Counter(some_iterable))`.

Here are some examples demonstrating the behaviour:

```
x = 'xyyxy'
print(Counter(x))         # Counter({'y': 3, 'x': 2}), i.e. most common first
print(list(Counter(x)))   # ['x', 'y'], i.e. insertion ordered
print(OrderedCounter(x))  # OC(OD([('x', 2), ('y', 3)])), i.e. insertion ordered
```

**Exceptions**

You should not use a regular `Counter` if additional or overwritten methods available to `OrderedCounter` are important to you. Of particular note:

1. `OrderedDict` and consequently `OrderedCounter` offer [`popitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.popitem) and [`move_to_end`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict.move_to_end) methods.
2. Equality tests between `OrderedCounter` objects are order-sensitive and are implemented as `list(oc1.items()) == list(oc2.items())`.

For example, equality tests will yield different results:

```
Counter('xy') == Counter('yx')                # True
OrderedCounter('xy') == OrderedCounter('yx')  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

Explained in comments

```
text_list = ['oranges', 'apples', 'apples', 'bananas', 'kiwis', 'kiwis', 'apples']


# create empty dictionary
freq_dict = {}
 
# loop through text and count words
for word in text_list:
    # set the default value to 0
    freq_dict.setdefault(word, 0)
    # increment the value by 1
    freq_dict[word] += 1
 
print(freq_dict )
```

```
{'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2}

[Program finished]
```