# Creating an Ordered Counter

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, ordereddictionary

I've been reading into how `super()` works. I came across [this recipe](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) that demonstrates how to create an Ordered Counter:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
     'Counter that remembers the order elements are first seen'
     def __repr__(self):
         return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__,
                            OrderedDict(self))
     def __reduce__(self):
         return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
```

For example:

```
oc = OrderedCounter('adddddbracadabra')

print(oc)

OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('a', 5), ('d', 6), ('b', 2), ('r', 2), ('c', 1)]))
```

Is someone able to explain how this magically works?

This also appears in the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes).

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you don't understand?

Comment: I see that the class inherits from Counter, and OrderedDict, but I can't see how these classes are combined to produce an OrderedCounter...I'm trying to understand what makes it work - for example, is there something special about Counter? Does this help clarify what I'm asking?

Comment: basically ,as a general rule of thumb, avoid multiple inheritance (your co-workers will not kill you this way) ... (of coarse mixins are a little different)

Comment: The example that you posted above is missing the __init__ method that is present in the documentation you linked to, and I'm not sure, but I would expect that to be important to making it work.  You can see that you override two methods.  Any method not overriden will be inherited from _Count_ and if not present will be inherited from _OrderedDict_.  If any method is on one of their superclasses it gets a little trickier.  As @JoranBeasley said "Avoid multiple inheritence" - the complex inheritance tree is why you want to avoid it (it leads to unexpected results).

Comment: Yeah, it all has to do with which `dict` methods `Counter` actually overrides/customizes. I can't figure out exactly which those would be, but I suspect `Counter` leaves `__setitem__` and `__iter__` untouched, so your new class gets those from `OrderedDict` and that's enough to give you the ordered behaviour.

Comment: @Matthew there is an `__init__` method in the python docs, but no `__init__` method in Raymond Hettinger's article. From my testing it works without the `__init__`.

Comment: oh, maybe this video may be interesting: [Raymond Hettinger - Super considered super! - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo)

Answer (score 40):

OrderedCounter is given as an example in the [OrderedDict documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#ordereddict-examples-and-recipes), and works without needing to override any methods:

```
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass
```

When a class method is called, Python has to find the correct method to execute. There is a defined order in which it searches the class hierarchy called the "method resolution order" or mro.  The mro is stored in the attribute `__mro__`:

```
OrderedCounter.__mro__

(<class '__main__.OrderedCounter'>, <class 'collections.Counter'>, <class 'collections.OrderedDict'>, <class 'dict'>, <class 'object'>)
```

When an instance of an OrderedDict is calling `__setitem__()`, it searches the classes in order: `OrderedCounter`, `Counter`, `OrderedDict` (where it is found).  So an statement like `oc['a'] = 0` ends up calling  `OrderedDict.__setitem__()`.

In contrast, `__getitem__` is not overridden by any of the subclasses in the mro, so `count = oc['a']` is handled by `dict.__getitem__()`.

```
oc = OrderedCounter()    
oc['a'] = 1             # this call uses OrderedDict.__setitem__
count = oc['a']         # this call uses dict.__getitem__
```

A more interesting call sequence occurs for a statement like `oc.update('foobar').` First, `Counter.update()` gets called.  The code for `Counter.update()` uses self[elem], which gets turned into a call to `OrderedDict.__setitem__()`.  And the code for *that* calls `dict.__setitem__()`.

If the base classes are reversed, it no longer works.  Because the mro is different and the wrong methods get called.

```
class OrderedCounter(OrderedDict, Counter):   # <<<== doesn't work
    pass
```

More info on mro can be found in the Python 2.3 [documentation](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/).

Answer (score 2):

I think we need to represent those methods `repr` and `reduce` in the class when words are given as input.

Without `repr` and `reduce`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    pass

oc = OrderedCounter(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'mango', 'apple', 'pie', 'mango'])
print(oc)
```

Output:

```
OrderedCounter({'apple': 2, 'mango': 2, 'banana': 1, 'cherry': 1, 'pie': 1})
```

The order in the above example is not preserved.

With `repr` and `reduce`:

```
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'
    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)
oc = OrderedCounter(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'mango', 'apple', 'pie', 'mango'])
print(oc)
```

Output:

```
OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('apple', 2), ('banana', 1), ('cherry', 1), ('mango', 2), ('pie', 1)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this way of creating the ordered counter the easiest in python3.
By casting the `Counter` to `dict`, print will use `__repr__` method of `dict` which will make sure, order is maintained!

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'mango', 'apple', 'pie', 'mango'])
OC = dict(c)
print(OC)
```

Output:

```
{'apple': 2, 'banana': 1, 'cherry': 1, 'mango': 2, 'pie': 1}
```