# Python: collections.Counter with deque-style ordering

Tags: python, counter, deque

I'm a relatively new Python (3) programmer.  I have a need for a data structure which seems to combine features of collections.Counter, deque, and set, and was hoping someone with more experience could suggest the most "pythonic" approach.

I have a sparse collection of integer indexes, and need to maintain counts associated with each index -- like a Counter.  But I also want to retain an implicit ordering between index:count pairs, so that I can e.g. remove the oldest one without knowing its index - like a deque.  Finally I'd like to be able to conveniently check for whether an index is present, like a set.  Lastly, in case it matters, I want to use rv_discrete from scypy.stats to select members with probabilty weighted by the count.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: How about `class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): pass`?

Comment: @timgeb I didn't know Python allowed multiple inheritance like that. Where can I read more about this in the docs?

Comment: @AkshatMahajan  well, it does :)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446015/creating-an-ordered-counter

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Python does allow multiple inheritance, but in general you can't combine classes like that and expect it to work.  This only works because of how `Counter` and `OrderedDict` are implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description, it sounds like an ordered counter should do most of that. The `OrderedDict` keeps track of insertion order and the `Counter` keeps track of the frequency of items.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
...     pass
>>>
>>> oc = OrderedCounter()
>>> oc[0] = 5
>>> oc[2] = 27
>>> oc
OrderedCounter({2: 27, 0: 5})
>>> oc.update({2:1, 0:6, 7:1})
>>> oc
OrderedCounter({2: 28, 0: 11, 7: 1})
>>> oc.popitem()
(7, 1)
>>> oc.popitem()
(2, 28)
>>> oc.popitem()
(0, 11)
```

You could get the first inserted key with `oc.keys()[0]`.