# How to count the same values in a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, counter

I have a `dict` that looks like this:

```
"votes": {
    "user1": "yes",
    "user2": "no",
    "user3": "yes",
    "user4": "no",
    "user5": "maybe",
    "user6": "yes"
}
```

What i want to do is, counting the same values so that i know that `yes` occurred 3 times, `no` occurred 2 times and `maybe` occurred 1 time.

What i do right now is this:

```
votes = OrderedDict()
for key, value in vote_dict["votes"].items():
    if value in votes:
        votes[value] += 1
    else:
        votes[value] = 1
```

It works fine but there is for sure a better way to do this. What would be a more pythonic way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can feed an iterable such as `dict.values` to `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

votes = {"user1": "yes", "user2": "no", "user3": "yes",
         "user4": "no", "user5": "maybe", "user6": "yes"}

res = Counter(votes.values())

print(res)

Counter({'yes': 3, 'no': 2, 'maybe': 1})
```

Comment: And actually, since i need to have a ordered counter, this is also interesting: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446015/creating-an-ordered-counter

Comment: Note in Python 3.6 (as an implementation detail) and 3.7+ (official), dictionaries are insertion ordered. Since this also applies to subclasses of `dict`, `collections.Counter` is also insertion ordered.