# How to find the count of different values for same key

Tags: python

```
Dict = [{'type':'a','no':'1'},{'type':'b','no':'2'},{'type':'b','no':'3'},{'type':'a','no':'4'},{'type':'c','no':'5'},{'type':'a','no':'6'}]
```

I need the count of values in type,
Output as follows

```
a = 3
b = 2 
c = 1
```

Comment: That is not a dictionary, that's a list of dictionaries with one key each

Comment: `get_type = itemgetter('type'); Counter(map(get_type, Dict))`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52027616/how-to-count-the-same-values-in-a-dict this might help you

Comment: There's multiple ways to do this. What do you have so far ? Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from collections import Counter
Dict = [{'type':'a'},{'type':'b'},{'type':'b'},{'type':'a'},{'type':'c'},{'type':'a'}]

lst = [v for a in Dict for k,v in a.items() if k=='type']


Dict = Counter(lst)
for k,v in Dict.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')
```

OUTPUT

```py
a = 3
b = 2
c = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an intermediate dictionary or even import Counter from the collections module. Here's how you could do it without any additional import:

```
Dict = [{'type':'a','no':'1'},{'type':'b','no':'2'},{'type':'b','no':'3'},{'type':'a','no':'4'},{'type':'c','no':'5'},{'type':'a','no':'6'}]
result = dict()
for d in Dict:
    result[d['type']] = result.get(d['type'], 0) + 1
for k, v in result.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')
```