# Python counter - numbers not in order

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple program that counts how many entries are in a file for a specific hour. I'm targeting the hour-part of the timestamp in the txt-file and counting each one. That all works well but when I print the result I want it to order the hours from 00, 01 and so on up to 22, 23.

This is my code:

```
hour = []
for x in hour:
    hour.append(x[10:12]) #To get just the hour-part of the timestamp.

hour_sorted = (sorted(hour)) #Now the hours are sorted from 00 to 23, all good so far.

counts = Counter(hour_sorted)

for number in counts:
    if number in counts:
        print(number + ' ' + str(counts[number]))
```

The problem is that now prints all the hours out of order.

Output example:

```
    10    3
    00    2
    12    2
    21    3
```

and so on. I want it like this:

```
    00    2
    10    3
    12    2
    21    3
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446015/creating-an-ordered-counter.

Comment: Hey, could you specify which version of Python your are using ? `collections.Counter` is a dictionary object, which ordering has changed a lot between python 2 and 3

Comment: Also, I think the `if` condition inside `for` loop is redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data structure that underlies `Counter` is a `dict`.
You can see this in [CPython's sources](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L472).
A `dict` in Python is a hashmap, which is, generally speaking, an unordered structure.
More specifically, it does not preserve the order of insertion.

Therefore, when iterating over the elements of a `Counter` instance, you won't get them in the same order as you stored them.

However, from Python 3.6, `dict`s are naturally ordered, so you'd get the behaviour you expect.
I'm running Python 3.7, and if I populate the `hour` list, that's what  I get:

```
00 2
10 3
12 1
21 1
```

The entries are printed in the order of insertion, that is, the order of `hour` after it's been sorted.

If you're not running Python 3.6 or later however, you must iterate over `hour` after it's been sorted so as to take that ordering into account:

```
hour_sorted = (sorted(hour))
counts = Counter(hour_sorted)

for hour in hour_sorted:
    print(hour, counts[hour])
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I will try this as soon as I get home :)

Comment: Had to remote to my computer and try it immediately. When I ran the same code in python 3 it all worked like a charm! Thanks for the fast and great help!

Answer (score 0):

you need to sort `Counter` object before youre for loop:

```py
...
counts  = sorted(counts.items())
...
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help! I will try this as soon as I get home :)