# Optimal/fastest way to count dates in a python list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, datetime, counting

I have a list of dates and the goal is to count the occurrences of each date **while maintaining the order** in which they appear in the original list. Consider the following example:

The list `only_dates` looks like this:

```
[datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 11)]
```

I am trying to use `groupby`:

```
import itertools
day_wise_counts = [(k, len(list(g))) for k, g in itertools.groupby(only_dates)]
print(str(day_wise_counts))
```

This prints

```
[(datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)]
```

I understand this is happening because ultimately each date object is being treated as a different one while grouping.

I was expecting the output to be:

```
[(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 2), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)]
```

I am not necessarily looking for a list of tuples. A dictionary output will also suffice as long as the original order of dates is maintained. (`OrderedDict` maybe).

How can I achieve this?

**Update:** There are possible multiple approaches being suggested which all work well. But I should have mentioned that I'll be doing this operation for a large amount data. So it would be great if your solution is optimal one in terms of running time. Please edit your answer/comment accordingly if you can.

**Update 2:** The size of data can be as large as 1 million rows.

Comment: If you're using python-2.x you could checkout this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446015/creating-an-ordered-counter how you could create an ordered Counter. Unfortunatly that doesn't work in python-3.x anymore (except for 3.6 where `dict` keeps it's order by default).

Comment: What sizes (and roughly what percentage of duplicates) are we talking about if you say "I'll be doing this operation for a large amount data."?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get count dict of items but maintain the order in which they appear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747564/how-to-get-count-dict-of-items-but-maintain-the-order-in-which-they-appear)

Comment: @MSeifert added an update to the question.

Comment: @Chris_Rands it does not address the performance requirement.

Comment: @PaleBlueDot It's still a dupe, but the answers here are better. If anything, that question could be linked to this one, I'll leave the moderators to decide this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, you could use an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import datetime

inp = [datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10),
       datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 11)]

odct = OrderedDict()
for item in inp:
    try:
        odct[item] += 1
    except KeyError:
        odct[item] = 1

print(odct)
```

which prints:

```
OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1),
             (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 2),
             (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)])
```

You also asked for timings, so here they are:

```
from collections import OrderedDict, Counter
import datetime
import random

# Functions

def ordereddict(inp):
    odct = OrderedDict()
    for item in inp:
        try:
            odct[item] += 1
        except KeyError:
            odct[item] = 1
    return odct


def dawg(inp):
    cnts=Counter(inp)
    seen=set()
    return [(e, cnts[e]) for e in inp if not (e in seen or seen.add(e))]


def chris1(inp):
    return [(item, inp.count(item)) for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(inp))]


def chris2(inp):
    c = Counter(inp)
    return [(item,c[item]) for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(inp))]


# Taken from answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23747652/5393381
class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):  
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)


# Timing setup
timings = {ordereddict: [], dawg: [], chris1: [], chris2: [], OrderedCounter: []}
sizes = [2**i for i in range(1, 20)]

# Timing
for size in sizes:
    func_input = [datetime.date(2017, random.randint(1, 12), random.randint(1, 28)) for _ in range(size)]
    for func in timings:
        res = %timeit -o func(func_input)   # if you use IPython, otherwise use the "timeit" module
        timings[func].append(res)
```

and plotted:

```
%matplotlib notebook

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for func in timings:
    ax.plot([2**i for i in range(1, 20)], 
            [time.best for time in timings[func]], 
            label=str(func.__name__))
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_xlabel('size')
ax.set_ylabel('time [seconds]')
ax.grid(which='both')
ax.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]

I timed it on Python-3.5. The approaches using `Counter` will likely be a bit slower on python-2.x (`Counter` was optimized for python-3.x). Also the `chris2` and `dawg` approach overlap each other (because there is almost no time difference between them).

So except for the first approach of [@Chris_Rands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44501340/5393381) and the `OrderedCounter` - the approaches perform very similar and mostly depend on the number of duplicates in your list.

It's mostly a factor of 1.5-2 difference. I couldn't find any real time difference for 1 million items bwteen the 3 "fast" approaches.

Comment: Nice, benhmark! How about the `OrderedCounter`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747564/how-to-get-count-dict-of-items-but-maintain-the-order-in-which-they-appear/23747652#23747652

Comment: @Chris_Rands I updated the answer. But it seems slower.

Comment: Try `sorted([(k,v) for k,v in Counter(dates).items()], key=lambda t: dates.index(t[0])) `  I think that may be the fastest...

Comment: @dawg I could measure it but sorting by the `index` introduces a tight correlation to the order of the input (that's a parameter that all other approaches avoided). In the best case it could be amazingly fast but in the worst case it's slow (`O(n**2)`). For example: `l = [datetime.date(2017, random.randint(1, 12), random.randint(1, 28)) for _ in range(2**19)]` then `%timeit dawg2(l)` gives `157 ms ± 3.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)` but `l2 = sorted(l)` and `%timeit dawg2(l2)` gives `13.9 s ± 143 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`.

Comment: So it could be 2-3 times faster but it could also be 50-100 times slower (compared to the other "fast" approaches").

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `list.count()` with a a list comprehension iterating over a list derived from an `OrderedDict` of unique ordered dates:

```
import datetime
from collections import OrderedDict

lst = [datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 11)]

[(item,lst.count(item)) for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))]
# [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 2), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)]
```

Or similarly using a `collections.Counter` instead of `list.count`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(lst)

[(item,c[item]) for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))]
# [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 2), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)]
```

Or use an [OrderedCounter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23747652/6260170).

EDIT: see the excellent benchmark by [@MSeifert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5393381/mseifert).

Comment: Looks good. +1 Please address the performance part of the problem if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Counter to count then [uniqify](https://stackoverflow.com/q/480214/298607) the original list to maintain order while adding the count.

Given:

```
>>> dates=[datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 11)]
```

You can do:

```
from collections import Counter

cnts=Counter(dates)
seen=set()
>>> [(e, cnts[e]) for e in dates if not (e in seen or seen.add(e))]
[(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 1), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 2), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 1)]
```

---

Update

You can also sort a Counter back into the order of the original list by using a key function to get the index of the first entry of date(X) in that list:

```
sorted([(k,v) for k,v in Counter(dates).items()], key=lambda t: dates.index(t[0]))
```

(The speed of this is correlated to how ordered or unordered your list is...)

---

Did someone say timeit!

Here are some timings with a larger example (400,000 dates):

```
from __future__ import print_function
import datetime
from collections import Counter
from collections import OrderedDict

def dawg1(dates):
    seen=set()
    cnts=Counter(dates)
    return [(e, cnts[e]) for e in dates if not (e in seen or seen.add(e))]

def od_(dates):    
    odct = OrderedDict()
    for item in dates:
        try:
            odct[item] += 1
        except KeyError:
            odct[item] = 1
    return odct

def lc_(lst):
    return [(item,lst.count(item)) for item in list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))]    

def dawg2(dates):
    return sorted([(k,v) for k,v in Counter(dates).items()], key=lambda t: dates.index(t[0]))    

if __name__=='__main__':
    import timeit  
    dates=[datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), datetime.date(2017, 3, 11)]*100000
    for f in (dawg, od_, lc_,sort_):
        print("   {:^10s}{:.4f} secs {}".format(f.__name__, timeit.timeit("f(dates)", setup="from __main__ import f, dates", number=100),f(dates)))
```

Prints (on Python 2.7):

```
 dawg1   10.7253 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
  od_    21.8186 secs OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)])
  lc_    17.0879 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
 dawg2   8.6058 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]0000)]
```

PyPy:

```
 dawg1   7.1483 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
  od_    4.7551 secs OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)])
  lc_    27.8438 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
 dawg2   4.7673 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
```

Python 3.6:

```
 dawg1   3.4944 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
  od_    4.6541 secs OrderedDict([(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)])
  lc_    2.7440 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
 dawg2   2.1330 secs [(datetime.date(2017, 3, 9), 100000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 10), 200000), (datetime.date(2017, 3, 11), 100000)]
```

Best.

Comment: Looks good. Please see my update to the question regarding performance. +1

Comment: Upvoted because you've put a lot into this solution, but I don't think using `sorted` is good because it may not necessarily preserve the original order. Also your benchmark is useful because it explores different Python versions, but MSeifert explores more parameter space

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Thanks.  The `sorted` version is using the index of the original list so how would it not preserve original order? It will be just as predictable as using any other method to preserve order.

Comment: @dawg Apologies I missed your custom sort key!