# How are Counter / defaultdict ordered in Python 3.7?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, counter, defaultdict

We know in Python 3.6 dictionaries are insertion ordered as an implementation detail, and in 3.7 insertion ordering can be relied upon.

I expected this to also be the case for subclasses of `dict` such as `collections.Counter` and `collections.defaultdict`. But this appears to only hold true for the `defaultdict` case.

So my questions are:

1. Is it true that ordering is maintained for `defaultdict` but not for `Counter`? And, if so, is there a straightforward explanation?
2. Should ordering of these `dict` subclasses in the `collections` module be considered implementation details? Or, for example, can we *rely* on `defaultdict` being insertion ordered like `dict` in Python 3.7+?

Here are my rudimentary tests:

**dict: ordered**

```
words = ["oranges", "apples", "apples", "bananas", "kiwis", "kiwis", "apples"]

dict_counter = {}
for w in words:
    dict_counter[w] = dict_counter.get(w, 0)+1

print(dict_counter)

# {'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2}
```

**Counter: unordered**

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

print(Counter(words))

# Counter({'apples': 3, 'kiwis': 2, 'oranges': 1, 'bananas': 1})
```

**defaultdict: ordered**

```
dict_dd = defaultdict(int)
for w in words:
    dict_dd[w] += 1

print(dict_dd)

# defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'oranges': 1, 'apples': 3, 'bananas': 1, 'kiwis': 2})
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Counter` and `defaultdict` are both ordered now, and you can rely on it. `Counter` just doesn't look ordered because its `repr` was designed before dict ordering was guaranteed, and [`Counter.__repr__` sorts entries by descending order of value](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.7.0/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L703).

```
def __repr__(self):
    if not self:
        return '%s()' % self.__class__.__name__
    try:
        items = ', '.join(map('%r: %r'.__mod__, self.most_common()))
        return '%s({%s})' % (self.__class__.__name__, items)
    except TypeError:
        # handle case where values are not orderable
        return '{0}({1!r})'.format(self.__class__.__name__, dict(self))
```

Comment: This is excellent. Just to add, it's possible to test this trivially by `list(Counter(words))`, i.e. the insertion ordering will be returned. Thank you!

Comment: Is the guarantee of order for defaultdict documented somewhere?