# Is it possible to call an iterator in a defaultdict to get the next key-value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary

Python 3.6.x

I've got a **defaultdict**, which is named `xref_to_records`. It has got strings as keys, and lists as values.

```
for k, v in xref_to_records.items():
    print(type(k))
    print(type(xref_to_records[k]))
    break
```

It produces:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'list'>
```

What I'm trying to do is to iterate through its items to compare the values list of a key against the next one. I know this question was probably already answered somewhere, but I couldn't figure to make work any of the provided approaches.

I've tried to iterate through the lenght of keys, but it doesn't work.

```
keys = xref_to_records.keys()
    for i in range(len(keys)):
    this_key = keys[i]
```

It raises me a *TypeError*:

> TypeError: 'dict_keys' object does not support indexing

I've tried also to iterate through keys using `next()` but unsuccessfully.

```
frick = None
for k,v in iter(xref_to_records.items()):
    if k != frick:
        res = next(k, None)
        print(res)
    break
```

Again a *TypeError* :

> TypeError: 'str' object is not an iterator

**Expected output**

```
for k, v in xref_to_records.items():
     somefunctions(k)
     somefunctions(next(k))
```

Comment: What's you excepted output?

Comment: Break is to block the iteration, isn't connected with the raised error.

Comment: You say you want to compare the values list "to the next one", but the values in a `defaultdict` are not ordered, so there is no clear "next one".

Comment: They're previously sorted. I've tried to print key:values, they're just in the expected order. Am I supposing something wrong? If not,  key *k* must be compared against key *k+1*

Comment: Do you want pairs (1,2), (2,3), ... or (1,2), (3,4), ...?

Comment: By luck it can happen that you receive the right order, but if you print it several times you should get shuffled (key:value) pairs

Comment: Pairs (1,2)(2,3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see below

```
from collections import defaultdict
xref_to_records = defaultdict(list)

xref_to_records['A'].append(9)
xref_to_records['A'].append(12)
xref_to_records['B'].append(99)
xref_to_records['B'].append(112)
xref_to_records['C'].append(99.34)
xref_to_records['C'].append(112.88)
xref_to_records['C'].append(4112.88)

keys = list(xref_to_records.keys())
for idx,key in enumerate(keys):
    if idx > 0:
        print('compare:')
        print('current:' + str(xref_to_records[key]))
        print('previous: ' + str(xref_to_records[keys[idx-1]]))
        print('')
```

output

```
compare:
current:[99, 112]
previous: [9, 12]

compare:
current:[99.34, 112.88, 4112.88]
previous: [99, 112]
```

Comment: Simple approach, no additional module.. So I was just forgetting to put keys into a list in order to enumerate them. It works

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, a dictionary does not have a specific order. However, in never versions of Python, the items in a `dict` should be iterated in the original order of insertion, and since `defaultdict` is a subclass of `dict`, [the same should hold there, too](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52174284/1639625).

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for i in range(4): d[i] = list(range(i+1))
>>> d[10] = []
>>> d[4] = []
>>> d
defaultdict(list, {0: [0], 1: [0, 1], 2: [0, 1, 2], 3: [0, 1, 2, 3], 4: [], 10: []})
>>> list(d)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 10, 4]
```

You can then get two `iter` of the dictionary, advance one of those once using `next`, and `zip` them to get pairs of `(current, next)` elements. (Here, it's just pairs of the keys, but of course you can just get the corresponding values from the dictionary.)

```
>>> from itertools import tee
>>> it1, it2 = tee(iter(d))
>>> next(it2)
>>> for a, b in zip(it1, it2):
...     print(a, b)
...
0 1
1 2
2 3
3 10
10 4
```

For older versions of Python, you might have to use a `collections.OrderedDict` instead. If, instead, you do not want insertion order but e.g. lexicographic ordering, you can just get the `iter` from the `sorted` keys.

Comment: This is a good answer because of the good example of zip but in my case for loop stops before expected printing just the first two keys (3 total).