# collections.Counter ordered as appear in list

Tags: python, counter

Is it possible to print in order as in list?

```
lis=['c','b','c','a','b','b']
collections.Counter(lis)
```

> Counter{'b':3,'c':2,'a':1}

But what I want is:

> Counter{'c':2,'b':3,'a':1}

Comment: first c then b then a

Answer (score 0):

This could do the trick:

```py
from collections import Counter, OrderedDict

class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict):
    'Counter that remembers the order elements are first encountered'

    def __repr__(self):
        return '%s(%r)' % (self.__class__.__name__, OrderedDict(self))

    def __reduce__(self):
        return self.__class__, (OrderedDict(self),)

lis=['c','b','c','a','b','b']
print(OrderedCounter(lis))
#OrderedCounter(OrderedDict([('c', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 1)]))
```

From [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747564/how-to-get-count-dict-of-items-but-maintain-the-order-in-which-they-appear)